# T-SQL Decimal Division Accuracy

Tags: t-sql, precision

Does anyone know why, using SQLServer 2005

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(30,15),146804871.212533)/CONVERT(DECIMAL (38,9),12499999.9999)
```

gives me 11.74438969709659,

but when I increase the decimal places on the denominator to 15, I get a less accurate answer:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(30,15),146804871.212533)/CONVERT(DECIMAL (38,15),12499999.9999)
```

give me 11.74438969

Comment: BTW The windows calculator gives 11.744389697096595117576772760941

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For multiplication we simply add the number of decimal places in each argument together (using pen and paper) to work out output dec places.

But division just blows your head apart. I'm off to lie down now.

In SQL terms though, it's [exactly as expected.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476(SQL.90).aspx)

```
--Precision = p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)
--Scale = max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)

--Scale = 15 + 38 + 1 = 54
--Precision = 30 - 15 + 9 + 54 = 72
--Max P = 38, P & S are linked, so (72,54) -> (38,20)
--So, we have 38,20 output (but we don use 20 d.p. for this sum) = 11.74438969709659
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(30,15),146804871.212533)/CONVERT(DECIMAL (38,9),12499999.9999)


--Scale = 15 + 38 + 1 = 54
--Precision = 30 - 15 + 15 + 54 = 84
--Max P = 38, P & S are linked, so (84,54) -> (38,8)
--So, we have 38,8 output = 11.74438969
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(30,15),146804871.212533)/CONVERT(DECIMAL (38,15),12499999.9999)
```

You can do the same math if follow [this rule](http://www.mathsteacher.com.au/year7/ch06_decimals/13_div_dec/dec.htm) too, if you treat each number pair as

- 146804871.212533000000000 and 12499999.999900000
- 146804871.212533000000000 and 12499999.999900000000000

Comment: Thanks. To be honest I used a FLOAT for my particular problem (as I don't need to be 100% accurate), but I was confused as hell as to what was going on when I was using decimals.

Comment: SQL server is unfortunately very bad in arithmetic :(  So, it is also worth to mention that, if you need accurate results for multiplication and division in t-sql, the best option is : To define and use CLR functions. See : http://www.skylinetechnologies.com/Insights/Skyline-Blog/March-2013/CLR-Functions-in-SQL-Server-A-Tutorial for a good intro

Answer (score 19):

To put it shortly, use DECIMAL(25,13) and you'll be fine with all calculations - you'll get precision right as declared: 12 digits before decimal dot, and 13 decimal digits after.
Rule is: p+s must equal 38 and you will be on safe side!
Why is this?
Because of very bad implementation of arithmetic in SQL Server!
Until they fix it, follow that rule.

Comment: Is there any reference material to say why this will be "fine" for all calculations?

Comment: `select cast(1000000 as DECIMAL(38,19)) / cast(9223372036854775807 as DECIMAL(38,19));` << OK
`select cast(1000000 as DECIMAL(25,13)) / cast(9223372036854775807 as DECIMAL(25,13));` << Arithmetic Overflow

Answer (score 18):

I've noticed that if you cast the dividing value to float, it gives you the correct answer, i.e.:

```
select 49/30                   (result = 1)
```

would become:

```
select 49/cast(30 as float)    (result = 1.63333333333333)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that you should be careful with this type of cast and not use it blindly. Decimals and floats store number representations differently and floats have some unintuitive effects that you should be aware of when doing this.

For example:

    select cast(cast(0.1 as float) as decimal(38,18))

Gives the output:

    0.100000000000000006

It's because 0.1 can't be accurately represented in binary, so it stores something slightly off. This can have an impact when you start multiplying or rounding things as the result might just be slightly off.

Answer (score 6):

We were puzzling over the magic transition,

> P & S are linked, so:

> 0. (72,54) -> (38,29)

> 0. (84,54) -> (38,8)

Assuming `(38,29)` is a typo and should be  `(38,20)`, the following is the math:

0. i. 72 - 38 = 34,
   ii. 54 - 34 = 20
1. i. 84 - 38 = 46,
   ii. 54 - 46 = 8

And this is the reasoning:

i. Output precision less max precision is the digits we're going to throw away.

ii. Then output scale less what we're going to throw away gives us... remaining digits in the output scale.

Hope this helps anyone else trying to make sense of this.

Comment: A typo (it should be i. 84 - 38(not 58) = 46, ii. 54 - 46 = 8). This is very useful @Campey

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeJoseph, I incorporated your correction back in May, but seem to have forgotten my thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Convert the expression not the arguments.

```
select  CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,36),146804871.212533 / 12499999.9999)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the following may help:

```
SELECT COL1 * 1.0 / COL2
```

Comment: Why do you think so?