# Choosing the appropriate precision for decimal(x,y)

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am currently redesigning a legacy database to run on SQL Server 2005, and I want to replace most of the old float-columns with decimals.

Decimal(15,4) would be sufficent for my needs but the [SQL Server doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746(SQL.90).aspx) states that this would use the same storage space (9 bytes) as a Decimal(19,4). Having a larger number in the same storage space seems like a good idea. So: is there any reason why I should *not* use the maximal precision of (19,4)? Performance drawbacks perhaps? Mind that I won't do extensive calculations in the database, only some SUMs or multiplications in queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason to use a smaller data precision, despite using the same amount of storage space, is to convey meaning to future users of the system. Which is also why it's important to use appropriate data types - e.g. DECIMAL(15,4) for numbers, MONEY for money.

Comment: I like the idea of "conveying meaning" instead of "getting the most digits out of my storage bytes".

Comment: To a point: I've had this backfire on me before when using the a higher scale would have avoided refactoring, despite the correct analysis and requirements

Answer (score 2):

For 4 decimal places, use money if you can

Reason: it's faster then decimal but is exact

[Money, float, decimal](http://sqlcat.com/technicalnotes/archive/2008/09/25/the-many-benefits-of-money-data-type.aspx) article

Edit: based on comment

Interesting argument. I follow both blogs.

Note the examples here: different precision based on datatypes and precedence

```
declare @d decimal(19,4), @ddiv decimal(19,4)

set @d = 12.39
SET @ddiv = 1000

select (@d/@ddiv)*@ddiv, (@d/1000)*1000
--Gives   12.390000    12.390000000
```

Explained by my answer here to "[T-SQL Decimal Division Accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423925/t-sql-decimal-division-accuracy/424052#424052)"

Now, this is interesting. Decimal, different answers

```
declare @d decimal(19,4), @ddiv decimal(19,4)

set @d = 12.39
SET @ddiv = 1001

select (@d/@ddiv)*@ddiv, (@d/1001)*1001
--Gives   12.390000    12.389999622
```

Back to money: same answer for each

```
declare @d money, @ddiv money

set @d = 12.39
SET @ddiv = 1001

select (@d/@ddiv)*@ddiv, (@d/1001)*1001
--Gives   12.3123    12.3123
```

**Moral: store in SQL, process in client languages...**

Comment: Thank you for the link. However, I'm a bit wary of the money datatype due to alleged inaccuracies as discussed here: http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.programming/browse_thread/thread/a4101df9f779d166/af6861dc4d5e0705?#af6861dc4d5e0705

Comment: I played around with your examples (thanks, btw), and the lesson I learned is "do not use literals" :) . I am still on the fence regarding the money vs decimal thing, though.

Comment: Personally, I'd go for money for performance and efficiency if you can offload your maths into the client. I use decimal(19,6) generally if I have any processing to do: I want to avoid precison/scale issues so I keep it all the same.

Comment: Guess I will go with decimal(19,6) then. Since it seems to be the same performancewise I will at least be covered if the customer needs to raise the scale or precision.

Answer (score 0):

Performance-wise, there is no reason for not using decimal(19,4). I personally don't think that using a different precision just to "convey meaning" makes sense, not only because proper documentation (even a comment on the field) would take care of this, but especially because business rules do change.

If using MONEY is the preferred choice instead, be aware of potential accuracy pitfalls: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/microsoft.public.sqlserver.server/4ZvwaOII3Vs