# Sql Server - Precision handling

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, rounding

I am just reading on the MSDN about [Precision Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx).

Taken out from the table on this site:

> Operation: e1 / e2
>
> Result precision: p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)
>
> Result scale: *max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)*

For the explanation of the used expressions:

`The operand expressions are denoted as expression e1, with precision p1 and scale s1, and expression e2, with precision p2 and scale s2.`

What I do not understand (more like I am not 100% sure I understand it) is this expression

`max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)`

Can someone explain it to me?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See my worked example here [T-SQL Decimal Division Accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423925/t-sql-decimal-division-accuracy/424052#424052)

It means maximum of `6` or `(scale1 + precision2 + 1)` for the scale of result