# Don't understand rounding behavior in sql server when using division operator

Tags: sql-server-2005, rounding

Could anybody explain what happens in the following sql code?

> declare @dividend numeric(38,22)
>
> declare @divisor numeric(38,22)
>
> declare @otherDivisor int
>
> set @dividend = 1
>
> set @divisor = 3
>
> set @otherDivisor = 3
>
> select cast(@dividend / @divisor as numeric(38,22)), @dividend / @otherDivisor

The result returned is

> ---
>
> 0.3333330000000000000000                0.3333333333333333333333

I would expect the same result for both calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

decimal(38,22) / decimal(38,22) ends up with decimal(x, 6) following [these rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476(SQL.90).aspx)

So you have 0.33333 before you cast back to decimal(38,22)

@otherDivisor is cast to (38, 0) and stays as decimal(x,22)

See my worked [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423925/t-sql-decimal-division-accuracy/424052#424052)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Are you aware of any way to work arround this behaviour?

Comment: @Ralf: It follows normal maths rules, just like multiplying decimal places in real life (2dp x 3 dp gives 6 dp). Float may be better, at the expense of some accuracy...

Answer (score 0):

Actually I take that answer back. It looks as though SQL is coercing the result to whichever has the higher precedence, dividend or divisor.

```
      select 1.00000000000000000000/3.0
      select 1.0/3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select cast(@dividend as numeric(38,22)) / @divisor, @dividend / @otherDivisor
```

You are casting after doing the division.