# SQL Server truncates decimal points of a newly created field in a view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, precision

I have a view in SQL server, something like this:

```
select 6.71/3.41 as NewNumber
```

The result is `1.967741` (note 6 decimal points) -> `decimal (38,6)`

I try the same thing in a calculator but the result is `1.967741935483871xxxx`

I want to force SQL Server to return more accurate result something like `decimal(38,16)`
I have tried the obvious things like casting, but SQL Server doesn't improve the output I just get some trailing zeros at the end like `1.9677410000`

Is there a way to force SQL Server to not truncate the result or give more accurate one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423925/t-sql-decimal-division-accuracy

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want something like `decimal(38,16)` then you need to cast the inputs not the output after truncation has already occurred!

```
SELECT CAST(6.71 AS DECIMAL(38,18))/3.41 AS NewNumber
```

Returns

```
1.9677419354838709
```

Check the datatype

```
SELECT 
SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(CAST(6.71 AS DECIMAL(38,18))/3.41, 'BaseType'),
SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(CAST(6.71 AS DECIMAL(38,18))/3.41, 'Precision'),
SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(CAST(6.71 AS DECIMAL(38,18))/3.41, 'Scale')
```

Returns

```
numeric 38  16
```

### Edit

This is just to add an additional link as follow up to the comments. The rules for `decimal` to `decimal` conversion [are described in BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx). That link includes the following phrase

> *The result precision and scale have an absolute maximum of 38. When a
>   result precision is greater than 38,
>   the corresponding scale is reduced to
>   prevent the integral part of a result
>   from being truncated.

but leaves it unspecified exactly how such truncation is performed. [This is documented here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/03/29/564110.aspx).

Comment: why Cast(6.71 as decimal(38,16))/Cast(3.41 as decimal(38,16)) returns 1.967741?

Comment: The result is datatype `decimal(38,6)`. The rules for the precision of the result of decimal division are in this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx result precision= `p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)` result scale = `max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)` But "when a result precision is greater than 38, the corresponding scale is reduced to prevent the integral part of a result from being truncated"

Comment: Thanks martin, others are working, your answer is very comprehensive

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit workaround, but I think it's worth a note.

```
select ((6.71*10000)/(3.41*10000)) as NewNumber
```

This query:

```
SELECT 6.71/3.41, ((6.71*1000000)/(3.41*1000000)) as NewNumber
```

returns:

```
1.967741    1.96774193548387
```

Answer (score 3):

The literal 6.71 is treated as a `numeric` which has a fixed precision.  Since you're doing division, you're changing the number of decimal places, which is not something you want to be using when accuracy is paramount.  If you want to treat your numbers like they're accurate, you need to cast the denominator in your query to be a `decimal` data type with a larger precision.  This should work for you:

```
select 6.71 / cast(3.41 as decimal(18, 8)) as NewNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to include decimal points:-

```
SELECT 5/3                          
--1

SELECT 5/(3*1.0)                    
--1.666666

SELECT ROUND((5/(3*1.0)), 2)        
--1.670000

SELECT ROUND((5/(3*1.0)), 3)        
--1.667000
```

But I still couldn't find a way to remove the zeros