# SQL Numeric data type truncating value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, decimal, numerical-methods

I really hope some SQL guru out there can assist with this one (and my apologies if this has been answered before. I did try and find a similar post but to no avail):

```
declare @theanswer numeric(38,16)

select @theanswer = 0.01 / 0.0074464347
select @theanswer
```

The above results in 1.3429245542165000

but the following (which looks the same to me)

```
declare @val1 numeric(38,16);
declare @val2 numeric(38,16);

set @val1 = 0.01;
set @val2 = 0.0074464347;

select @val1/@val2
```

results with 1.342924 and truncates it?

Any ideas?

Comment: On Sql-Server 2008 I got `1.3429245542165000`

Comment: Try out `select @theanswer = CAST(0.01 as numeric(38,16)) / CAST(0.0074464347 AS numeric(38,16))`

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL Decimal Division Accuracy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423925/t-sql-decimal-division-accuracy)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385326/sql-server-truncates-decimal-points-of-a-newly-created-field-in-a-view/5385417#5385417

Comment: select @val1/@val2 AS  conv_factor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the real precision and scale for the result (@val1/@val2) I would execute this `T-SQL` script

```
DECLARE @val1 NUMERIC(38,16);
DECLARE @val2 NUMERIC(38,16);

SET @val1 = 0.01;
SET @val2 = 0.0074464347;

SELECT @val1/@val2
        ,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@val1/@val2, 'BaseType')  [BaseType]
        ,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@val1/@val2, 'Precision') [Precision]
        ,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@val1/@val2, 'Scale')     [Scale]
```

And the results will be:

```
(No column name)    BaseType    Precision   Scale
1.342924            numeric         38          6
```

So, the result precision is 38 and result scale is 6.
MSDN has some details regarding precision and scale for arithmetic operations. These information can be found here: [Precision, Scale, and Length (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx):

```
Operation = e1 / e2
Result precision = p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)
Result scale * = max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)
```

Using these formulas we can write the next `T-SQL` script to get theoretical precision and scale for the result (@val1/@val2) :

```
SELECT   @p1 = 38   --or CONVERT(INT, SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@val1, 'Precision'))
        ,@s1 = 16   --or CONVERT(INT, SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@val1, 'Scale'))
        ,@p2 = 38   --or CONVERT(INT, SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@val2, 'Precision'))
        ,@s2 = 16   --or CONVERT(INT, SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@val2, 'Scale'));

--SELECT    @p1 [@p1], @s1 [@s1], @p2 [@p2], @s2 [@s2];

SELECT  @p_result = @p1 - @s1 + @s2 +   CASE 
                                            WHEN 6 >= @s1 + @p2 + 1 THEN 6 
                                            WHEN 6 < @s1 + @p2 + 1 THEN @s1 + @p2 + 1 
                                        END
        ,@s_result =    CASE 
                            WHEN 6 >= @s1 + @p2 + 1 THEN 6 
                            WHEN 6 < @s1 + @p2 + 1 THEN @s1 + @p2 + 1 
                        END;

SELECT  @p_result [@p_result], @s_result [@s_result];
```

The result is:

```
@p_result   @s_result
93          55
```

So, for this arithmetic operation (@val1/@val2), in `theory` the precision and scale are `93` and `55` but the real precision and scale are `38` and `6`.
The real precision is 38 because *"**The result precision** and scale **have an absolute maximum of 38**"*.

Regarding the real result scale (6) MSDN it's not clear: *"When a result precision is greater than 38, **the corresponding scale is reduced** to prevent the integral part of a result from being truncated"*.

To see how "the corresponding scale is reduced" I executed the above tests (script 1 for real precision and scale and script 2 for theoretical precision and scale) using `NUMERIC` values having the same scale (16) but different scales (from 16 to 38). The results of these tests are:

```
/*
Result prec. Result scale   (T=theoretical value, R=real value)
 T-R         T-R            --@val1 and @val2 data type
49-38       33-22           --NUMERIC(16, 16)
51-38       34-21           --NUMERIC(17, 16)
53-38       35-20           --NUMERIC(18, 16)
55-38       36-19           --NUMERIC(19, 16)
...
61-38       39-16           --NUMERIC(22, 16) -- <-- data type for [real] result scale 16
...                         
77-38       47-8            --NUMERIC(30, 16)
79-38       48-7            --NUMERIC(31, 16)
81-38       49-6            --NUMERIC(32, 16)
83-38       50-6            --NUMERIC(33, 16)
85-38       51-6            --NUMERIC(34, 16)
...
93-38       55-6            --NUMERIC(38, 16)
*/
```

Examining these results:

1.I see an arithmetic progression for the real result scale: from 22 to 6, step -1.

2.Also, if the scale for @val1 and @val2 is constant (`NUMERIC(...,16)`) then an inverse correlation exists between @val1 & @val2 precision (from 16 to 32) and the [real] result scale (from 16 to 6).

3.If @val1 and @val2 precision is 32 or higher (`NUMERIC(32->38,16)`) the the [real] result scale is always 6 => this is your case.

4.If a greater [real] result scale is needed (over 6) you need to use a lower precision for @val1 
and @val2: `NUMERIC(22, 16)`:

```
SELECT          
         CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,16),@val1) / CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,16),@val2) [CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,16)]
        ,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY( CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,16),@val1) / CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,16),@val2) , 'BaseType')  [BaseType]
        ,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY( CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,16),@val1) / CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,16),@val2) , 'Precision') [Precision]
        ,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY( CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,16),@val1) / CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,16),@val2) , 'Scale')     [Scale] 

CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,16) BaseType Precision Scale
---------------------- -------- --------- -----
1.3429245542165299     numeric  38        16
```

Comment: I'm just a SQL Server enthusiast. Nothing more.