# Precision, Scale, Sum, Divide.. Truncation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the following code:

```
SELECT -701385.10 -- -701385.10
SELECT SUM(-701385.10) -- -701385.10
SELECT -701385.10/2889991754.89 -- -0.000242694498630
SELECT SUM(-701385.10)/2889991754.89 -- -0.000242
```

In the last `SELECT` the result is truncated to 6 decimal places.  I've read through the [Precision, Scale, and Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) article and unless my working is wrong, I can't understand why the truncation is occurring.  The type of the expression `SUM(-701385.10)` should be `DECIMAL(38,2)` - see [SUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) - so the type resulting from the division should have:

Precision:

- p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)
- 38 - 2 + 2 + max(6, 2 + 10 + 1)
- 38 - max(6,13)
- 38 - 13
- 25

Scale:

- max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)
- max(6, 2 + 10 + 1)
- max(6, 13)
- 13

So why are the decimal places being truncated?

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL Decimal Division Accuracy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423925/t-sql-decimal-division-accuracy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your working is wrong

```
Precision: p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)
Scale: max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)
```

Gives

```
Precision: 38 - 2 + 2 + max(6, 2 + 12 + 1) = 53
Scale: max(6, 2 + 12 + 1)                  = 15
```

Which is greater than 38 so you are getting truncation [as covered here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/03/29/564110.aspx)