# Division using Convert Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Precision, Scale, Sum, Divide.. Truncation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271966/precision-scale-sum-divide-truncation)

I've got a question. I've programmed a function but I'm having some problems when I divide 2 numbers using convert. Here is an example:

```
Declare @A Numeric(18,6)
Declare @B Numeric(18,6)

Set @A = 1
Set @B = 130
```

If i do the following query the result is : `0.007692307692307692`

```
Select Convert(Decimal(30,18),@A / @B)
```

But if I do this the result is: `0.007692300000000000` (losing decimals)

```
Select Convert(Decimal(30,18),Convert(Decimal(30,18),@A) / Convert(Decimal(30,18),@B))
```

Can someone please explain why I'm losing decimals if I'm using the same precision and scale?

Comment: When the theoretical precision from division exceeds 38 scale gets truncated to 6 decimal places. The theoretical precision formula for division of decimal/decimal is documented in books online.

Comment: Instead of jumping twice through that old (nicely answered SO question), here's the end link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/03/29/564110.aspx