# SQL Server wrong mathematical result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this statement:

```
Select (30 - 5) * 700 / 30 as A , 700 - (5 * 700 / 30) as B
```

which has two ways to calculate the same equation.

These two equations should result in 583.33 if you made them by your calculator
but the previous statement results in 583 for field A, and 584 for field B.

Both are wrong and both are integer not decimal.

I want to know what's the right way to write this statement so I can get 583.33.

Thanks

Comment: You need to cast it in select statement first see here. [Cast select result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259254/select-19-12-return-1-i-need-in-decimal-that-is-1-58-sqlserver-2005)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Cast` function:

As next:

```
   Select Cast((30 - 5) * 700 as DECIMAL(19,2) ) / 30 as A , 
          700 - ( Cast (5 * 700 as decimal (19,2 )) / 30) as B
```

**Result**:

```
A              B
583.333333  583.333334
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is implicitly using an `INT` datatype. Try it this way to allow it to use a `DECIMAL` datatype

```
Select (30.000 - 5.000) * 700.000 / 30.000 as A ,  
       700.000 - (5.000 * 700.000 / 30.000) as B
```

Comment: Select (30 - 5) * 700.00 / 30 as A , 700.00 - (5 * 700.00 / 30) as B
resutled 583.333333

Comment: If you want specific rounding, use `ROUND` or `CEILING` or `FLOOR` or `CAST` to change the result