# Sum rows and then calculate formula vs calculate formula row by row and then sum

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, math

I have stupid math problem. In `T-SQL` why are these two sums different:

```
select (34.3+17.5 + 13.5)/31.0*28.0   --= 58.9806280

select 34.3/31.0*28.0 + 17.5/31.0*28.0 + 13.5/31.0*28.0  --= 58.9806000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculation are done with the operator priority rule, and regarding the type of your numbers.

The first one `select (34.3+17.5 + 13.5)/31.0*28.0` is done in 3 steps:

- `select (34.3 + 17.5 + 13.5) -- = 65.3`
- `select 65.3 / 31.0          -- = 2.106451`
- `select 2.106451 * 28.0      -- = 58.9806280`

The second one is done this way:

- Priority to the division:

  `select 34.3 / 31.0 -- = 1.106451
  select 17.5 / 31.0 -- = 0.564516
  select 13.5 / 31.0 -- = 0.435483`
- Then:

  `select 1.106451 * 28.0 -- = 30.9806280
  select 0.564516 * 28.0 -- = 15.8064480
  select 0.435483 * 28.0 -- = 12.1935240`
- Finally:`select 30.9806280 + 15.8064480 + 12.1935240 -- = 58.9806000`

And if you go deeper, take a look at this one too:

```
select cast(34.3 as float)/31.0*28.0 + 17.5/31.0*28.0 + 13.5/31.0*28.0
-- => 58,9806451332903
```

My english is not that good, and somebody else has already pointed out what you're asking for, so if you want to know why numbers are rounded that way, there are 2 great links that can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/424052/4584335 and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: From the Department of Unexpected Results: `select 30/2/5; select 30/-2/5; select 30/-2./5; select 30/(-2)/5;`. See [here](http://w3facility.org/question/sql-server-strange-math-result/) for more information. A change in _documented_ operator precedence between [SQL Server 2000](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276846%28v=sql.80%29) and [2005](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) makes this reasonable, if rather unconventional.