# SQL auto converts decimal to numeric when select & insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, format

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 and linked SQL Server 2012.
When I do the following

```
SELECT * INTO dbo.Local_table FROM dbo.Linked_table
```

all decimal columns automatically get converted into numeric.

What is the reason and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: provide sample data of `dbo.Linked_table`

Comment: How do you know that the output is numeric, not decimal?

Answer (score 1):

This is automatic conversion that occurs with most SQL Servers. You'll find this happening with at least, but not limited to, server year versions 2000-2014. I don't know of a way to get rid of this restriction because it's a built in server feature which restricts arithmetic equations via query statements.

Here is another SO question/answer which might help you:
[T-SQL Decimal Division Accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423925/t-sql-decimal-division-accuracy/424052#424052)

Here is some MSDN for clarification: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx