# DECIMAL 16 bits of precision

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, math, decimal

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious here, but I have a query where I need the result to be to 16 bits of precision after the decimal.

Below is an example query.

```
select (CONVERT(decimal(38,16), 467897.78) * 12) / CONVERT(decimal(38,16), 8143372.15)
```

If I run that query from SSMS, the result is `0.689489` , however, if I run that exact same math problem from just the windows calculator app, the result it shows is `0.6894899627054337` . Am I missing something with my tsql query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL Decimal Division Accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423925/t-sql-decimal-division-accuracy). Note that if you leave out your `CONVERT`s altogether, you'll get `0.689489962705`, which is closer to the desired result.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert that was it.

Comment: Note that, though the answers mention using `FLOAT` (and it is often the case that floating-point is either good enough, or actually what you want), `select CONVERT(DECIMAL(38, 16), 467897.78 * CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 16), 12) / 8143372.15)` would also do in this case. It's a bit of a black art to tweak precisions for decimals, given the complicated rules, but for `FLOAT`, you're still left with formatting afterwards if you need to actually show the digits (`select FORMAT(467897.78e * 12e / 8143372.15e, 'G16')`, the default formatting has one digit less).

Comment: select CAST((467897.78 * 12) / 8143372.15 as Decimal(38,16))

Comment: @DrDoomPDX: that only casts the end result and thus has much worse accuracy; `0.6894899627050000` is accurate only to 12 digits.

Comment: DECLARE @a float = 467897.78
DECLARE @b float = 12
DECLARE @c float = 8143372.15

select CAST((@a * @b) / @c as decimal(38,16))

Comment: Try this: `SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,16),(CONVERT(decimal(10,2), 467897.78) * 12) / CONVERT(decimal(14,4), 8143372.15))` (you have a typo in your expected answer, it's ...054377, not ...054337).