# Why Decimal(20,10) returns better value of Pi than Decimal(38,10) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

When executing the following query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(22) AS decimal(38, 10) / CAST(7) AS decimal(38, 10) AS pie
```

the output is: 3.142857.

But when I run the same query with lower precision of 20 I get more values after the decimal

```
SELECT
    CAST(22) AS decimal(20, 10) / CAST(7) AS decimal(20, 10) AS pie
```

The output is : 3.142857142857142857

Can anyone explain why this is so?

I have a similar situation in SQL Server where I need the accurate value up to 10 decimal places when I divide two `decimal(38, 10)` columns.

Problem being, these two columns are coming from a separate table, where they are defined as `DECIMAL(38, 10)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [T-SQL Decimal Division Accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423925/t-sql-decimal-division-accuracy)

Answer (score 2):

There are only 38 digits of storage, so scale can be lost to preserve high-order digits in calculations.

This is all explained in the docs:

[image]

[Precision, scale, and Length (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: So is there a way i can cast the two columns down to 20,10 just for the computation purpose and to achieve accuracy of 10 decimal places ?

Comment: Yes.  Cast them to a lower-precision decimal or to float for the calculation.  Or better yet, reduce the declared precision of the columns.

Comment: Declared precision cannot be reduced as the columns were defined by the DBA , i can just create a Table Valued Function or View over it. Casting them to a lower precision gives an error saying trying to cast numeric to data type numeric. And float just returns the value till 6 decimals